# Memory error with np array when making document term matrix in python 2.7

Tags: python

I am using `matrix = np.array(docTermMatrix)` to make DTM. But sometimes it will run into memory error problems at this line. How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using 32bit python.  32bit python limits your program ram memory to 2 gb (all 32bit programs have this as a hard limit), some of this is taken up by python overhead, more of this is taken up by your program. normal python objects do not need contiguous memory and will map disparate regions of memory

`numpy.arrays` require **contiguous** memory allocation, this is much harder to allocate. aditionally `np.array(a) + 1`  creates a 2nd array and must allocate again a huge contiguous block (in fact most operations).

some possible solutions that come to mind

1. use 64 bit python ... this will give you orders of magnitude more ram to work with ... you will be unlikely to encounter a memory error with this unless you have a really really really big array (so much so that numpy is probably not the right solution)
2. use multiprocessing to create a new process with a new 2gb limit that just does the numpy processing stuff
3. use a different solution than numpy( ie a database)

Comment: You are right, I am using 32 bits. Never know this before. Thanks.